# Login test with laravel dusk

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, testing, laravel-dusk

I started browser testing with laravel dusk.
Using a test database (sqlite), creating a user with a model factory and using the `Browser::loginAs` method worked. 
But when I try to simulate a real login, I get an Error:

```
General error: 1 no such table users.
```

I have a .env.dusk.local file with and specified `DB_CONNECTION=sqlite` and `DB_DATABASE=:memory:`
I also tried it with a sqlite file. Then I got the error

```
Database (tests.sqlite) does not extis.
```

I've read that the problem could be, dusk and the application open different connections.
How should I configure the database connections to get this working?

Comment: Did you properly initialize your database and run migrations?

Comment: @tadman I think so. I can create an user with a model factory and I can also use the loginAs function. Only the login through the LoginController and the AuthentesUser trait seems to not run the migrations. I'm also confused about the 'Database does not exists' error, when I'm using an sqlite file.

Comment: When it's complaining a table doesn't exist I'm inclined to believe it doesn't exist. You'll have to check that it was created properly. There are desktop clients for opening .sqlite files, so you could peek in there and see what's up.

Comment: @tadman It looks like dusk runs the migration, because I can create and search for users, login and logout. But it seems like the application itself is using another connection or something like that and doesn't run the migration. And so my question is, how do I have to configure the database connections and/or the test environment to have dusk and the application using the same database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you cannot use `:memory:` database while running Laravel dusk. Because dusk and testing server are running on separate processes. Dusk can't access to database created on development server.

See my answer here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50376781/7917269